# What snake is this one?

Tags: species-identification, herpetology

I'm wondering what kind of snake is the one in the attached photo. It looks like *Vipera aspis* but It seemed a bit too big (lenght of about 1 meter).
[image]

This photo was taken near Como, in the north of Italy, in the woods of Parco Spina Verde.

Comment: Did the snake have dark V on his head?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't tell.. the snake quickly run away and I didn't have enough time to look closely the details on his body

Comment: So i think you really cant expect much more then my answer. Unfortunatly because i want to know true name..

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be Vipera aspis, but that leght what did you descripe is really rare. Anyway it can be Smooth Snake(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_snake) too. But you know personaly i cant do more from this point of view. The smooth snake is much more common and longer so there is a bigger possibility.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a very nicely patterned individual of the recently newly described [Barred grass snake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barred_grass_snake). Used to be part of *[Natrix natrix](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-07847-9)*. Non venomous, not dangerous.